# How can we parse and deal with BigNumber (BN) args in Solidity events?

Tags: solidity, web3js, events, bignumber

In the past, web3 events published numeric events like so:

```
BigNumber { s: 1, e: 17, c: [ 1000 ] } }
```

Now with web3.js 1.0, big numbers come down as objects like this:

```
 <BN: de0b6b3a7640000>
```

The problem here is that if we're collecting events for troubleshooting later, this would be indecipherable. The only solution I can think of is having some code in the event consumer convert the number before storing the event somewhere like so:

```
web3.utils.fromWei(new web3.utils.BN(receipt.logs[0].args.amount))
```

Does anyone else have any other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You have access to `yourBigNumber.toString(10)`, `.toString(16)` and `.toNumber()`, no?

Look at this cheatsheet https://github.com/MikeMcl/bignumber.js